# Movement in outer space via Newton's law of every action has an equal and opposite reaction

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, acceleration, conservation-laws, rocket-science

What is more effective for travel in outer space ignoring all other factors like air radiation etc. I have a 10 kg bag of rice would I travel faster throwing the whole bag at once or throwing a grain at a time compounding my tiny acceleration or would they end up being equal?

Comment: It's better to throw it all at once. You can prove this via calculus, I'll post it tomorrow morning, but the basic intuition is that when thrown in small pieces, the average velocity of the trailing stream of rice is smaller than the velocity of the single bag, since the individual rice were thrown in a comoving frame with the person; by conservation of momentum, the person will be moving more slowly after throwing the individual rice than after throwing the entire bag.

Comment: You might find http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation interesting. In a nutshell, it decribes how carrying your fuel affects your final velocity.

Answer (score 1):

You need a model for how you throw the rice.  The obvious one is that you can expel any mass at the same velocity $v$ relative to you.  Letting $M$ be your mass (without the rice), $V$ your velocity in the CM frame, if you throw it as one lump we have momentum conservation.  You start with no momentum in the CM frame, so $10v=MV, V=\frac {10v}M$.  If you throw it as bits, the later bits have less velocity in the CM frame because they start with some velocity in your direction.  Your velocity is therefore lower.  If you can throw small bits faster than the whole bag, we need to reassess, but you need to specify the model.

Answer (score 1):

This has a simple closed-form solution. Denoting $m_0,m_1$ as the initial and final person's mass, $v_r$ as the rice speed and $\delta=m_0/m_1$, if the bag is thrown in one single parcel, we have
$$\Delta v_1=(\delta-1)v_r$$
By the rocket equation, if the rice is thrown continuously, we have
$$\Delta v_2=v_r\text{Log}(\delta).$$
But
$$\text{Log}(\delta)\leq \delta-1$$
for all $1\leq\delta\leq\infty$, so $\Delta v_1\geq\Delta v_2$.

Answer (score 0):

Given a bag of rice of mass $m_b$ that you can throw with a maximum acceleration $\vec{a}_b$, by Newton's second law, the most force $\vec{F}_b$ you could exert on the rice is given by

$$\vec{F}_b = m_b \vec{a}_b$$

By Newton's third law, the reaction force (acting on you) $\vec{F}_{you}$ is given by

$$\vec{F}_{you} = - \vec{F}_b = - m_b \vec{a}_b$$

Again by Newton's second law, if you have mass $M$, your acceleration would be given by

$$\vec{a}_{you} = - \frac{m_b}{M} \vec{a}_b$$

Now imagine you throw the $N$ individual rice grains with masses $m_i$ one at a time, each with the same acceleration $\vec{a}_b$ that we imparted on the bag. Because the mass of the bag of rice is just the sum of the masses of all the little grains of rice,

$$\sum_{i = 1}^N m_i = m_b$$

Newton's second law says that the force $\vec{F}_i$ on each grain of rice is given by

$$\vec{F}_i = m_i \vec{a}_b$$

By Newton's third law,

$$\vec{F}_{you, i} = - m_i \vec{a}_b$$

So your acceleration due to each grain of rice is

$$\vec{a}_{you, i} = -\frac{m_i}{M} \vec{a}_b$$

Summing over $i$ to find your total acceleration gives

$$\vec{a}_{you} = \sum_{i = 1}^N \vec{a}_{you, i} = \sum_{i = 1}^N -\frac{m_i}{M} \vec{a}_b = -\frac{1}{M} \vec{a}_b \left(\sum_{i = 1}^N m_i \right) = -\frac{m_b}{M} \vec{a}_b$$

Therefore the acceleration caused by throwing the whole bag at once and that caused by throwing each grain of rice individually are equal (provided the rice grains are all thrown in the same direction, of course).

Comment: The assumption $\sum \vec{a}_i = \vec{a}_b$ is not obvious, and is suspect. You seem to be claiming that a person can impart a *much lower* acceleration to a single grain of rice than they can give to a whole bag of rice. On the other had you also have a mistake in your summation algebra: $\sum_i x_i y_i \ne (\sum x_i)(\sum y_i)$, so your first mistake does not drive your conclusion as far off as it would if you had done the rest of the math right.

Comment: Oh, you're definitely right about that. I'm sorry, that was a serious oversight. I'll fix up my answer now, thank you.

Comment: In your sum over $i$, the $M$ in the denominator should be $M -m_i$.  That is, your total mass decreases for each grain of rice you throw.